# $stateProvider and some ionic tags are not working in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ionic-framework

I'm working on windows phone 8.1 application using visual studio ultimate 2013. In app.js I wrote the following code for routing:-

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file)|data:image\/|\/?img\//);
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0)|\/?app\//);
}])

    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

           .state('app', {
               url: "/app",
               abstract: true,
               templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
               controller: 'MainCtrl'
           })

            .state('app.login', {
                url: "/login",
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
                        controller: 'MainCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })

        // fallback route
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');

    });
```

But on windows phone 8.1 it didn't work although above code worked on wp8 emulator.
Then I used $routeProvider it worked on wp8.1 device but with $routeProvider we can't use 'abstract' and I need 'abstract' for my menu.
 How could I solve this problem, if there is any solution with $stateProvider itself then it would be better?

I'm confronting one more problem: For my Windows Phone 8.1 application I'm using Ionic Framework. But some directives like 'ion-view' , 'ion-content', so on… are not working on Windows Phone 8.1 device:

So, What could be the reason and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Windows is not officially supported by Ionic. It is on their roadmap, but not currently supported. See their documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for your prompt response

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, it is possible to get Ionic working with Win/WinPhone 8.1. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx